# Преобразование даты php

Tags: php, дата

Есть дата в таком формате 25 июль 2016, необходимо получить 2016-07-25 делаю так

```
       echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dbtArr[1]));
```

Получаю 1970-01-01 03:00:00. Что делать? Надеюсь найдется способ без explode и переборов синонимов для месяцев.

Comment: 1970-01-01 03:00:00 - это начало отсчета unixtime + 3 часа часового пояса. Т.е. strtotime не смог распознать ваш формат даты.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, вы дату `25 июль 2016` храните именно в виде строки?

Comment: @Visman, да, это парсер, на странице донора дата в таком формате.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь таким костылем:

```
$dbtArr[1] = '25 июль 2016';
$dbtArr[1] = str_replace(array('январь', 'февраль', 'март', 'апрель', 'май', 'июнь', 'июль', 'август', 'сентябрь', 'октябрь', 'ноябрь', 'декабрь'), array('january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'), $dbtArr[1]);
echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dbtArr[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ без  explode и переборов синонимов для месяцев:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU', 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'ru', 'russian');  
echo strftime("%B %d, %Y", time());
```

21-ый век: есть локализация, и корректный разбор даты и времени.